# Object in to a array

Tags: php, arrays

I got this below array object in PHP

```
 Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => maintenance
            [value] => N
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [key] => color
            [value] => B
        )
 )
```

how can I covert it to look like

```
 Array (
    [maintenance] = >N
    [color] => B
  )
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply loop through the array

```
$new = array();
foreach($item as $i) {
    $new[$i->key] = $i->value;
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Darrne...your loop worked perfectly for my need.

Answer (score 1):

try with -

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($yourArray as $object) {
    $newArray[] = (array) $object;
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: Ow, you are very watchfull )) I didn't match that there is array as income

Answer (score 1):

just typecast it

```
$array =  (array) $yourObject;
```

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

> If an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose
>   elements are the object's properties. The keys are the member variable
>   names, with a few notable exceptions: integer properties are
>   unaccessible; private variables have the class name prepended to the
>   variable name; protected variables have a '*' prepended to the
>   variable name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't get me what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$outArray = array();
foreach($yourArr as $obj){
    $outArr[$obj->key] = $obj->value;
}
```

Iterate over all elements

Comment: Thanks but it didn't get me what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Universal function to convert objects in a array

> ```
> public function objectToArray($d) {
>
> if (is_object($d)) {
>     // Gets the properties of the given object
>     // with get_object_vars function
>     $d = get_object_vars($d);
> }
>
> if (is_array($d)) {
>     /*
>      * Return array converted to object
>     * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
>     * for recursive call
>     */
>     return array_map(array($this, 'objectToArray'), $d);
>     //$this->d = get_object_vars($d);
> }
> else {
>     // Return array
>     return $d;
> } }
> ```

Comment: let me know if it is not helpful :)

Comment: Thank you Sharma...but  Darrne loop worked perfectly. Check below

Comment: yes i know but i just give you optimize solution,recursion is much faster than loop, and what if there is multidimensional set of objects